# what's the different with using $scope and explicitly using ctrl as namespace?

Tags: angularjs, scope

We can use `$scope` as a namespace in angularJS

```js
    angular.module('myApp',[])
           .controller("myController", function($scope){
            $scope.info = "Hello";
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
         <input type="text" ng-model="info">
         {{info}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

or we can use `this` explicitly in `controller` and use the controller name as namespace in view like:

```js
    angular.module('myApp',[])
           .controller("myController", function(){
            this.info = "Hello";
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
         <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.info">
         {{ctrl.info}}
    </div>
</body>
```

My question is what's the difference and what choose to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer in the link [Angularjs "Controller as" or "$scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641478/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope) gives explanation on the controllerAs vs $scope.

Also, from my own experience, i prefer controllerAs syntax. Because, i usually add dynamic data to an Array of objects.

When using $scope option, the ng-repeat was not able to refresh itself when a new data was pushed into the Array, like $scope.dataArray

When using controllerAs syntax, whenever i push a data into the dataArray object, the ng-repeat adds the new data into view.

This happens mainly because, when using $scope syntax, any change to the array creates a new reference. However, using controllerAs syntax, the array reference is always maintained.

Refer [ng-repeat not updating on update of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849293/ng-repeat-not-updating-on-update-of-array)

Comment: Thanks @Neerajkummar,  I checked the referred answer. So, we are recommended to use "Controller as" syntax right? Are there other pits I should be aware of when using that syntax other than `$scope` ? Cause I read the [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) it rarely mentioned using the `Controller as` syntax, but most examples chose the `$scope`.

Comment: @Neerajkummar, searching `Controller a vs scope` give me some good duplicate questions, will dig into those and close this question, thanks for the effort and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Happy to help @armnotstrong ! So far i have not seen any issues in using the ControllerAs syntax. While using custom directives, initially i found it difficult, as i was unaware of how to use ControllerAs in custom directives. But there is always stackoverflow to help us. Cheers !!!